# Como limpar a tela do Idle do Python?

Tags: python, idle-ide

Como limpar a tela do Idle do Python?

Após varias entradas fica poluído e ruim para visualizar.
Isso é possivel de maneira prática?

Answer (score 1):

Não há um comando nativo da própria IDLE, mas é possível fazer isso com bibliotecas externas.

Você pode fazer utilizando a `os`, por exemplo:

```
import os
os.system('clear') # se estiver utilizando linux
os.system('cls') # se estiver utilizando o windows
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize

```
import os
os.system('clear') or None
```